# How to write an NFT mint script properly?

Tags: javascript, smartcontracts, web3js, nft

I was following this [tutorial by freecodecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-make-an-nft) on how to create and mint an NFT and since it is a little old I faced some issues but I was able to figure most of them out. Nevertheless, I spent like 2hrs on the last step of minting the NFT and couldn't resolve the issue unfortunately. It was the last time of running the mint script that would mint the deployed contract and store the NFT in my wallet.

```
// ethereum/scripts/mint.js
// ethereum/.env
require("dotenv").config({ path: '../.env' });
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

const contract = require("../artifacts/contracts/happyBunny.sol/HappyBunny.json");
const contractInterface = contract.abi;

// https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers
const provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider("sepolia", {
  alchemy: process.env.DEV_API_URL,
});

// https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Wallet
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, provider);

//https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract
const happyBunny = new ethers.Contract(
    process.env.CONTRACT_ADDR,
  contractInterface,
  wallet
);

const main = () => {
  happyBunny
    .mint(process.env.PUBLIC_KEY)
    .then((transaction) => console.log(transaction))
    .catch((e) => console.log("something went wrong", e));
};

main();
```

The process.env.CONTRACT_ADDR is the msart contract's address that has been succesfully deployed already. I suppose that is the address required for that function right?

At one point I realized that the script couldn't access the .env file so i modified the dotenv path inside the first line where I import the dotenv package but I still had another error. The error was as follows:

something went wrong

> Error: quorum not met (request="%sub-requests", info={ "request": { "method": "estimateGas", "transaction": { "data": "", "from": "my_wallet_address", "nonce": 1, "to": "Contract_address" } }, "results": [ "{"error":{}}", "{"result":{"type":"bigint","value":"92339"}}" ] }, code=SERVER_ERROR, version=6.6.0)

- *Deleted the value of data for safety issues.*